# Monitorar corrida em esteira, com o celular

Tags: javascript, algoritmo, java-8

**Contexto**:
Utilizando os sensores do celular, preciso definir um padrão de corrida na esteira, para saber a velocidade média e a distância percorrida.

Criei um programa para imprimir os valores dos sensores no eixo `x`, `y` e `z`, e com base nisso encontrar um padrão. O programa gera os dados, mas não consigo encontrar padrão algum.

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como solucionar esse problema?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Talvez você tenha usar como base o número da variação anterior e verificar se a variação atual é alta ou baixa, assim você determinaria a velocidade, por exemplo. Mas para determiná-la você precisaria de saber também sobre o tamanho da passada da pessoa, se a esteira está inclinada ou não, a altura da pessoa, etc, etc. Parece impossível apenas com essas informações... Geralmente aplicativos com esse tipo de comportamento funcionam bem com GPS e Bússola, determinando o tempo corrido através da localização do aparelho em uma corrida de rua.

Comment: Aparentemente o GPS nessa situação é inútil, uma vez que o dispositivo não sairá do local. Não tenho certeza, mas creio que terás que usar AccelerometerPlay para isso. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview

Comment: @DiegoVenâncio, sim, GPS é inútil. O exemplo que dei foi sobre uma *corrida de rua*.

Comment: Primeira coisa que você deve fazer é eliminar o ruído dos seus dados. Um sensor, mesmo parado, irá variar em suas medidas, então você precisa eliminar do sinal esta variação para não gerar falsos verdadeiros no seu sistema. Em vários livros sobre processamento digital de sinais você conseguirá achar algoritmos para isso.

Comment: O programa criado para analisar os dados,

Comment: O programa usado para obter os dados funciona, assim após 5 segundos ele começa a pegar os valores de x y z dos censores do celular, quando der 1 minuto o programa para, eu estes com umas quatro pessoas, e varias velocidade, do 6km/h ao 18km/h. Uma ideia que eu tive foi pegar a força, pois para cada felicidade, a pessoa séria que usar mais ou menos força, mas o meu chefe, falou e se a pessoa que estiver correndo pular muito a força irar ser maior, depois que ele falou isso quebrou toda minha ilha de raciocínio. Muito obrigado para que está tentando dar uma força na solução desse problema.

Comment: Segue o programa para teste no link http://dev.cloudgym.com.br/game/